# Include the whole package or only the specific class?

Tags: java

In my program i have to use sort function of the `Collections` class.
Is that compile time remains same in both the cases?

- Case 1: `include import java.util.Collections;`
- Case 2: `import java.util.*;`

What I thought is that the second case is gonna take long time to search for the `Collections` class, if there are other import packages.

Please correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Imports are only used to resolve class names, this is done before compilation. The overhead of searching whole packages should be negligible.

Comment: Am actually participating in some code challenges, So do u think it makes the difference in compile time? even in mili seconds

Comment: I would not worry about this. This is a matter of milliseconds at most.